# CMake target RUN_TESTS was not generated

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cmake

What may be the reason that CMake target RUN_TESTS was not generated in Visual Studio 2015? I can't include the complete CMakeLists.txt as it is huge and consists of many subprojects with own CMakeLists.txt, but it contains `enable_testing()` command executed, tests are added and built, there is simply no predefined target. Other predefined targets like: ZERO_CHECK, INSTALL, ALL_BUILD are there.
My cmake execution is:

```
cmake -C conaninitialcache.cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug <source_path>
```

Could it be the Conan's fault?

Comment: Does your CMakeLists.txt contains a `enable_testing()` command? Otherwise no target `RUN_TESTS` is created in the Visual Studio solution.

Comment: Where is the `enable_testing()` command located within your CMake project?

Answer (score 7):

It turns out, that when having a project with subprojects, `enable_testing()` must be located in the root CMakeLists.txt, not in the subprojects, since as the documentation says:

*This command should be in the source directory root because ctest expects to find a test file in the build directory root.*

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_testing.html